# Is there a way to give a function two random parameters, and have them be the same?

Tags: java

Say I want to call a built in function (meaning I cannot change it):

```
foo(int x,  int y)
```

And I want the parameters of x and y to be random, but be the *same* random number. I know I can do this with

```
double rand = Math.random();
foo(rand, rand);
```

However, is there any way to do this in one line, without declaring a separate variable? Such as

```
foo(Math.random(), Math.random());
```

but have them be the same. Just curious if there's a simple way to do this I'm not aware of that avoids adding the extra line. Maybe something I can feed into the second parameter that basically tells it "make this the same as the first parameter"? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you concerned only about the function calling part?

Comment: Why? What's the problem with the two line version? It's what I would write.

Comment: @johnKugelman I agree.  But I took it to be an academic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah so this can be easily done by creating another method that takes 1 parameter and calls the original method. This ensures the value is always the same when calling this method. If you don't want the original foo(int, int) to be used publicly, don't expose it and hide it as package private or private.

```java
foo(int value) {
    foo(value, value);
}
```

```java
foo(Math.random());
```

Answer (score 4):

Define a lambda or a method

```
Function<Integer, Integer> fnc = v -> foo(v,v);
fnc.apply((int)(Math.random()*10));
```

or

```
public static int foo(int x) {
  return foo(x, x);
}

public int static foo(int x, int y) {
     return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The `random()` method generates a new number between 0.0 and 1.0 every time it is called. Even alternatives such as using the `Random` and `ThreadLocalRandom` classes behave the same way with their respective methods.

You have two options:

1. You can store the result of calling `Math.random()` and pass that value through `x` and `y`, just as you mentioned in your post.
2. You can have only one parameter in your function:

   ```
   foo(int x)
   ```

   Now you can just pass the desired value. However, if you want to have a function that has two parameters, you can call the method as such:

   ```
   foo(int x) {
       foo(x, x);
   }
   ```